# Error (only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars) when trying Calculating maximus

Tags: python, numpy

Iam trying to calculate maximas from the below code but getting error as
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Input_list= [1,9,96,9,7,4,3,77,0,2,3,4,5].

Please help

```
import ast,sys
import numpy as np
input_str = sys.stdin.read()
input_list = ast.literal_eval(input_str)

from scipy.signal import argrelextrema

Ar=np.array(input_list)
maximas=argrelextrema(Ar, np.greater) #store your final list here
maximas=[int(x) for x in maximas] #do not change this code, the output should be an integer list for evaluation purposes
print(maximas)
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace of the exception ? It may be useful in order to establish where is the error cause.

Answer (score 1):

`argrelextrema` returns a tuple containing the arrays (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html).  For your case, you probably want to access the first element of this tuple, so something like

```
maximas=[int(x) for x in maximas[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.argrelextrema.html), the `scypy.signal.argrelaxtrema` function returns a tuple of arrays, with one value for each dimension of the input. If the input is one-dimensional, you'll get a 1-tuple back.

I suspect you can fix your code with `maximas = argrelextrema(Ar, np.greater)[0]`, or maybe `maximas, = argrelextrema(Ar, np.greater)` (note the comma after the variable name, which makes it an unpacking!).

Answer (score 0):

```
In [295]: from scipy.signal import argrelextrema                                                                           
In [296]: Ar = np.array([1,9,96,9,7,4,3,77,0,2,3,4,5])                               
In [297]: maximas=argrelextrema(Ar, np.greater)
```

When you ask about an error, you should show all of the error message, or at least enough so both you and we know were it occurs.  That's useful information.

```
In [300]: [int(x) for x in maximas]                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-300-0250728a7b76> in <module>
----> 1 [int(x) for x in maximas]

<ipython-input-300-0250728a7b76> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 [int(x) for x in maximas]

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Most likely the error is in the `int()` call, since `int` is meant to return **one** integer, either from a string or a numeric input.  The error indicates that `x` was an array with more than one value.

Look at `maximas`:

```
In [301]: maximas                                                                    
Out[301]: (array([2, 7]),)
```

It's a tuple, containing one array.  So iteration on that tuple will produce an array.

We can select the array from the tuple with indexing:

```
In [302]: maximas[0]                                                                 
Out[302]: array([2, 7])
In [303]: maximas[0].tolist()   # convert it to a list                                                        
Out[303]: [2, 7]
In [304]: maximas[0].astype(int).tolist()   # ensure it's integers                                         
Out[304]: [2, 7]
```

According to the docs the result of `argrelextrema` is a tuple, one array per dimension of the input.  In fact the code shows it returning `np.nonzero(results)`. More commonly we use the `np.where(results)` alias.

There was no need to use `int(x)`.  `maximas` arrays are integer, indices.

You might not need to convert `maximas` to a list.  The result of `np.where` can often be used directly in indexing, for example:

```
In [307]: Ar                                                                         
Out[307]: array([ 1,  9, 96,  9,  7,  4,  3, 77,  0,  2,  3,  4,  5])
In [308]: Ar[maximas]                                                                
Out[308]: array([96, 77])
```

===

Be ware that if the input array is 2d, `maximas` will be a 2 element tuple.

```
In [312]: Be = Ar[:12].reshape(6,2)      # 2d array                        
In [313]: argrelextrema(Be, np.greater)                                              
Out[313]: (array([1, 3]), array([0, 1]))    # 2 element tuple
In [314]: Be[_]              # using the tuple to index Be                                               
Out[314]: array([96, 77])
```